# Firebase reset password link is not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase, and need to reset password for the user. All method called successfully, and email with link is received.

However, when user click on this link - it is quickly opens the window and closes it with out any message.

Same is happening when I am reseting password from Firebase console.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Earthling, please post code of what you have so far.Also tell us the language that you are coding in... peace. \/   :)